# maxItemsInObjectGraph ignored

Tags: wcf

I have a problem with a WCF service, which tries to serialize too much data. From the trace I get an error which says that the maximum number of elements that can be serialized or unserialized is '65536', try to increment the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota.

So I went and modified this value, but it is just ignored (the error is the same, with the same number). All this is server-side. I am calling the service via wget for the moment.

My web config is like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceBehavior">
       <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="131072" />
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
   <customBinding>
    <binding name="customBinding0" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="16384"
                                maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="16384"
                                maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
   </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceBehavior"
    name="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding0"
     contract="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

---

---

---

Version 2, not working either:

```
 <system.serviceModel>  
  <behaviors>

    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceEndpointBehavior">
         <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="131072" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>

   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
   <customBinding>
    <binding name="customBinding0" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="16384"
                                maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="16384"
                                maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
   </customBinding>
  </bindings>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceBehavior"
    name="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapService">
     <endpoint 
        address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding0"
        contract="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapService" 
        behaviorConfiguration="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceEndpointBehavior" />
    <endpoint 
        address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  
        behaviorConfiguration="AlgoMap.Web.MapService.MapServiceEndpointBehavior" />
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone help?? 
Thanks!!

Comment: You need to set it in the client configuration aswell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any setting put in the web.config were happily ignored, I haven't found out why. But I found a workaround, that is, to put the MaxItemsInObjectGraph as a **class decoration**. This works flawlessly:

```
// MyService.svc
// using...

namespace MyNamespace {
  [ServiceContract]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  [ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 65536000)]
  public class MyWebService {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "tree/{sessionId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public MyData GetTree(string sessionId) {
    ...
...
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for 8 hours, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well, in my instance, I had forgot to place this setting in my client app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

May be it is small yet? did you try to give larger value like 655360000? Note that you should change the value in client's and Server's config files. My guess is that you changed only in one part ;)

Comment: No, it is not small, it is just IGNORED by the server. In the exception I still see the default limit. I do not have any client-side configuration as I am calling this through wget, and in the final product I'll be calling it with a WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

From a little search in Google, it seems you are adding the setting in the wrong place.

You need to create a new `behavior` in the `endPointBehaviors` section (not `serviceBehaviors`).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. Using service behavior attribute at the class level works fine, which make sense. I prefer config level change. I have added the config entries both at the client(web.config) and service level(app.config). Did this work for you?