# DataContractJsonSerializer and maxItemsInObjectGraph

Tags: wcf, webhttpbinding, datacontractjsonserializer

How can I set the maxItemsInObjectGraph for the DataContractJsonSerializer?

I get an error saying `"Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota."`

Where does the number 65536 come from. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx) for DataContractJsonSerializer says the default is Int32.MaxValue.

I tried to set it in the behavior configuration:

```
 <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <dataContractJsonSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="500000"/>
    </behavior>
 </endpointBehaviors>
```

but I get an error like: `"Invalid element in configuration. The extension name 'dataContractJsonSerializer' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions."`

Changing the behavior to `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="500000"/>` gives no error but doesn't change the value (which is no surprise since I'm not using the dataContractSerializer)

The client is created with a ChannelFactory so I can't use the ServiceBehavior attribute as described here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325321/maxitemsinobjectgraph-ignored/2871685#2871685)

Comment: Blew right past the dataContractSerializer bit in the question, removing the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do it via config (haven't tried), but you can increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph property on the code, and it should work. In the example below, if I don't increase it, the call fails; otherwise it succeeds.

```
public class StackOverflow_5867304_751090
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Product> GetProducts(int size);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public List<Product> GetProducts(int size)
        {
            List<Product> result = new List<Product>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                result.Add(new Product { Name = "Prod " + i, Price = i });
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        return new WebHttpBinding() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue };
    }
    static void AddBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsob = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            if (dcsob != null)
            {
                dcsob.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 1000000;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        AddBehavior(endpoint);
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        AddBehavior(factory.Endpoint);
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetProducts(100000).Count);

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```