# How to return a Dictionary of custom type values as a regular JSON object from a WCF REST method?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

Let's say I've got a custom type that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool HasPaid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Owner
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and a WCF REST interface that looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Dictionary<string, CompositeType> GetDict();
}
```

then how do I get my implementation of that method to return a JSON object that looks like this...

```
{"fred":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Fred Millhouse"},"joe":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Joe McWirter"},"bob":{"HasPaid":true,"Owner":"Bob Smith"}}
```

I do *not* want it to look like this:

```
[{"Key":"fred","Value":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Fred Millhouse"}},{"Key":"joe","Value":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Joe McWirter"}},{"Key":"bob","Value":{"HasPaid":true,"Owner":"Bob Smith"}}]
```

Ideally I would prefer not to have to alter the return type of the method.

I have tried many different approaches but cannot find a solution that works. Annoyingly, it is easy to produce the right-shaped JSON object structure in one line with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

where `dict` is defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, CompositeType> dict = new Dictionary<string, CompositeType>();
dict.Add("fred", new CompositeType { HasPaid = false, Owner = "Fred Millhouse" });
dict.Add("joe", new CompositeType { HasPaid = false, Owner = "Joe McWirter" });
dict.Add("bob", new CompositeType { HasPaid = true, Owner = "Bob Smith" });
```

but I do not want to return a string from my WCF method. This is because it conceals the real type being returned; and also because WCF serializes the string as well, resulting in escaped double quotes and other ugliness that makes it harder for non-.Net REST clients to parse.

Comment: It's not easy.  You want to set [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it's never exposed, so you'll need to replace the entire serializer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792785 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003016.  Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504 would be simpler though.

Comment: I agree with @dbc. Another problem with `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` that it's not working well with nested dictionaries. So you really need to think about switching to another JSON serializer.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the pointers. Is there really no easier way to do this? Can you configure `dataContractJsonSerializer` somewhere in `web.config`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6139402/1843329 seems to suggest you can only configure it programmatically. To simplify things I don't need nested dictionaries and I'm pretty sure the keys for the dictionary will always be `string` in my case.

Comment: Whoopee - thanks @dbc! I tried your simpler suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3131413/1843329 - i.e., returning a [`Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message(v=vs.110).aspx) and that gets me the right-shaped JSON if I just do `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
            return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(json, "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);` To my pleasant surprise, unlike `Stream`, with `Message` I _can_ see the HTTP GET response in my browser.

Comment: @snark - good news!  Might I suggest that you answer your own question, since this has come up before with no answer, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494436/how-to-change-the-datacontractjsonserializersettings-for-a-restful-wcf-service-o

Comment: @dbc - I did think that but I'm minded to leave the question unanswered in case someone does come up with a simple answer that doesn't involve changing the return type of the method, as I originally asked. At least, thanks to you, I have something that works now! I will post a comment on their question though, suggesting the `Message` approach...

Comment: @dbc - good idea - done!

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial solution in response to comments by @dbc. It results in the right-shaped JSON structure of this...

```
{"fred":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Fred Millhouse"},"joe":{"HasPaid":false,"Owner":"Joe McWirter"},"bob":{"HasPaid":true,"Owner":"Bob Smith"}}
```

but unfortunately involves having to change the return type of the method to [`Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message(v=vs.110).aspx). The interface becomes:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Message GetDict();
}
```

and the implementation becomes:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
...
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Message GetDict()
{
    Dictionary<string, CompositeType> dict = new Dictionary<string, CompositeType>();
    dict.Add("fred", new CompositeType { HasPaid = false, Owner = "Fred Millhouse" });
    dict.Add("joe", new CompositeType { HasPaid = false, Owner = "Joe McWirter" });
    dict.Add("bob", new CompositeType { HasPaid = true, Owner = "Bob Smith" });

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(json, "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

One useful feature to note is that, unlike when returning [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx), you *can* view the JSON easily in your web browser when you visit the REST method's URI.