# Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph... with knowtypes

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, datacontractserializer

In a WCF 4.0 service we receive a huge amount of data in a generic list. This list object graph is bigger than the 65536 default limit. We are quite used to it, so we have configured the service for being able to getting those big graphs.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

With the above chunk of xml config we have avoided the problem in the past with no problem, but now it doesn't work. The only difference is that here we are using **KnownTypes** in the huge list elements that we are trying to deserialize in the WCF method.

Maybe, am I missing some special configuration for knowntypes?

Comment: And you are certain that its the MaxItemsInObjectGraph that's being exceeded and not, for example, the MaxReceivedMessageSize?

Comment: the exception is clear 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65535' :(

Comment: Does your service declare a behaviorConfiguration attribute? If so it won't pick up the default one above

Comment: In my tests and in other services it does, but I will try defining everything.

Comment: The behavior block you show above is unnamed - in .NET 4 this will act as a default for any services that do not explicitly declare a behaviorConfiguration. If your service does (to, for example, expose metadata) then this change to the maxItemsInObjectGraph will not be picked up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to check client configuration.

See similar answers in [How to fix MaxItemsInObjectGraph error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298209/how-to-fix-maxitemsinobjectgraph-error/6298356#6298356)

> You need to set the MaxItemsInObjectGraph on the
>   dataContractSerializer using a behavior on both the client and
>   service.

and [maxItemsInObjectGraph ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325321/maxitemsinobjectgraph-ignored/4455209#4455209)

> I had forgot to place this setting in my client app.config file

.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/258278, put the following ServiceBehavior attribute on the class definition as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue)]
public class MaintenanceResource
```

Comment: In production it is recommended to specify real expected value,rather then MaxValue, and config file is a flexible option, but attribute is not flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Michael said, I needed to add a behavior on my client like this (in web.config of my site):

```
<behavior name="deepGraph">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
</behavior>

...

<client>
    <endpoint address="..." behaviorConfiguration="deepGraph" ... />
</client>
```